# GDK Assertion IS_Window failed

Tags: flet

I am trying to run flet code on ubuntu 22.04 and keep getting the following error message
(flet:6177): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 11:08:50.080: gdk_window_get_state: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

What could be wrong? I have updated my system so its not about updates.

I have tried to run flet code  on ubuntu 22.04 and I keep getting the following error message.

(flet:6177): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 11:08:50.080: gdk_window_get_state: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

what could be wrong? my system is up to date.

Comment: I have a same problem with Ubuntu 23.04 and Flet 0.19.0
I just started learning Flet

Comment: run with sudo worked